# Why obvious False result of logical AND operation cancels out FOR loop iteration

Tags: c#

My question is why this condition in a `for` loop makes it cancel out iteration, however it seems to me that condition is fulfilled?! If I try with one of two given variables without using AND operator looping works and continues infinitely.

```
bool a = false;
bool b = false;
for (; a && b == false; )
{
    Console.WriteLine("");
}
```

Comment: It seems to me that you think your code is comparing `a` and `b` to false, that's not true. Only `b` is compared to false and `a` is expected to be true

Comment: thank you, i was screwing my head what was wrong with it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This condition

```
a && b == false
```

means

```
a && (b == false)
```

Since `&&` does **[short circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)**, the first false will result in `false` for whole expression, and thus there is no need to evaluate second expression.

Also to add, even with a single `&` (which doesn't perform short circuit evaluation, your complete condition will result in `false`.

If you want to compare both `a` and `b` to false you can do:

```
a == false && b == false
```

or

```
!a && !b
```

You should also consider using a `while` loop, if there is no iteration variable involved.

Answer (score 3):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323%28v=vs.71%29.aspx
Because the `==` is evaluated before `&&`, the condition is `a && (b == false)`
so false.

Comment: I think your answer is the most on point. The other answers, either don't answer the question, or add too much irrelevant information that only obscures the answer to the question. +1